# "Yet" to imply negative?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions, negation

> Yet few colleges and universities have taken sufficient account...

Does the sentence above imply a negative/opposite meaning? e.g:

> Few colleges and universities haven't taken sufficient account...

Comment: Yes, but only because _few_ is a [negative trigger](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), as you can see if you use _a few_ instead. That changes the meaning drastically, since _a few_ is affirmative.

Comment: Can't believe I asked this lol

Comment: Nice pdf anyway =)

Comment: @JohnLawler: I think you've misread the question (as I did at first). You're right that the negative polarity of "few" changes the discourse meaning of "yet", but it does not change the truth-value of the sentence in the way that Mouse Hello's second example suggests.

Comment: @ColinFine: Perhaps. And perhaps you've misread my comment. It's obvious the poster didn't notice that _few_ itself is a negative, and it's obvious that's where the ungrammatical second example comes from. The negativity of _few_ was the only point I wanted to make in my comment (and why I didn't comment as an Answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It implies a negative meaning from the sentence *preceding* it — it does *not* negate the "to take" verb in this sentence. The meaning is actually this:

> However, few colleges and universities have taken sufficient account...

Answer (score 2):

There is one formal expression, "be yet to." Ex.

> Few colleges are yet to take sufficient account.

In this case, yes, although the structure is positive the meaning will be negative.

But in your particular example above, *yet* is used as a conjunction. It means something like "surprisingly however." Ex.

> The minister of education emphasized the gravity of the issue. 
>   *Yet* few colleges and universities have taken sufficient account.

So, and to answer your question, the "few colleges" did "take sufficient account."

Comment: I think your first example would actually be positive, implying *Most colleges have now taken account...*  Did you mean *A few*?

Comment: Hi Tim. It depends on what we mean by "positive/ negative." When I teach, "negative" sentences are those that are negated or have the word "not." This is why I mentioned that, structurally, "be yet to" is positive. But semantically, it's equivalent to "haven't p.p. yet"

Comment: All I meant was that your sentence appears to contain a double negative; sorry if I have confused the issue.

Comment: Got it, Tim. Actually, I also realized the ambiguity that "few" and "a few" presented in my example. So your comment was perfectly valid :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it reflect the negative sense but not negating its verb in fact it is the another way to say

> Many of colleges and universities have not taken sufficient account...